# Making a spectrum analyzer probe

Tags: spectrum

I bought this dirt cheap Spectrum analyzer from a Chinese web site. It arrived and all it had was an antenna. I have very little experience with spectrum analyzers, how can I build a probe for this equipment. The equipment expects a 50 ohm probe and it has BNC connector.

So far, I took a BNC cable, ripped one side, soldered a 805 50 ohm resistor to the tip and left the ground alone to make measurements. Does this make sense?

Comment: Usually probes are not a simple resistor; anyway I assume you have put it between the tip and the ground right?

Comment: @clabacchio hmm.. I didn't do that, I just connected the 50 ohm to the tip, should I connect it between the gnd and tip? Than use the tip side to touch the circuit?

Comment: heres a old home made way to make one
<http://emcesd.com/1ghzprob.htm>

Comment: Yes: the reason is because the probe must have an input resistance of 50Ohm to match and have the stationary waves in phase. But if you put it only in the tip, it will be in series with the internal resistance of the instrument (usually around 10M) and will be useless

Comment: @clabacchio, And the OP, 50ohm is not a simple resistance, if you place a 50 ohm resistor in series you will cause a missmatch. 50Ohm is the [wave impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_impedance). If you cut a 10 foot 50ohm cable in half you will have two 5-foot 50 ohm cables, not two 25 ohm cables.

Comment: @Kortuk I'm not expert about probes, I was just trying to explain why putting the 50 Ohm in series is not working...but I don't even know how a probe is built.

Comment: @i_bryn: I think that link qualifies for an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

To be happy with it, you're going to want a length of 50-ohm coaxial cable with a BNC plug on one end. You'll attach your probe (whatever you find handy) to the opposite end. No resistors.

Answer (score 0):

a probe is usually a megaohm input to a (in this case a 50ohm) Spectrum Analyzer across all bands. Either its a wideband step down transformer or a wideband active device (tubes have been successful for VTVM in the past with highest input impedance)